# OnItemClickListener() - Android listview

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I was developing a sample app in Android and came across below code, I am just wondering what part of Java,OOPS concept is used when this line is used , can any one please explain in detail this kind of declaration ? why its being declaraed like this

```
mainlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    } });
```

Answer (score 3):

This is called an [Anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), in this example used as part of an [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at observer and command pattern. These pattern help you to understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

[OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) is an [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).
The ListView will save the interface implementation you gave (your `new OnItemClick...`).
And when the ListView detects a user click on item it will call the callback you gave (your implementation) via `mOnItemClickCallback.onItemClick(params...)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what "metter" has stated,

this

```
mainlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        } });
```

can also be written as

```
 mainlistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

/// do the stuff for item click

}
```